Chicken or Egg. Does everything begin or is the idea of start/first/origin related to the use of language?
The existence of beginning: origin/start/initiate. Do not all beginnings require something before? Are all just arbitrary measurements of traits we find of interest? The globally persuasive ideas of creation myths rely on a first beginning before anything, and do something with no evidence of something coming from nothing ever witnessed.
Does this mean there was never any beginning? Does this leave only explanation that existence has always just existed? Or is the very nature somehow an abuse or misunderstanding of applied language?

Welcome to this site. This seems more like a start of a discussion than something that can have a straightforward answer, and thus is not a good fit for this site.

(Since ur new out here) you will find that serious philosophical questions will generally get closed. Just a lay of the land FYI...

@marcticus I took you up on your encouragement to polish the question. Feel free to roll back if I misunderstood.

There is an argument called the Kalam Cosmological Argument, primarily advocated by Christian apologist William Lane Craig, which deals with this.  He has two relatively short videos explaining the overview of the argument; part 1 here, and perhaps of more interest to your question, part 2 here.  In summary, it goes like this:

Whatever begins to exist must have a cause.
The universe began to exist.
Therefore, the universe has a cause.

The supports given for Premise #2, which concerns your question, are these:
Scientific supports

The fact the universe is running out of usable energy implies a definite beginning (entropy argument).
Modern scientific theories and evidence favor a beginning of the universe.

Philosophical supports
The existence of an actually infinite number of past events cannot exist in the real world:

Hilbert's Hotel: An example hotel with an actually infinite number of rooms leads to absurdities.  For example,
(a) If all the rooms in this infinite hotel are full, a guest can still check in if the manager bumps everyone into the next room over, opening room #1, even though all rooms were full to begin with.
(b) If an infinite number of guests show up, the manager can bump everyone into a room number twice that of his or her current room, opening an infinite number of odd-numbered rooms; again, even though all rooms were already full.
(c) If all odd-numbered guests check out, an infinite number of guests is still in the hotel; yet if all guests in rooms 4 and above check out, only three guests are left; but in both cases, the exact same number checked out (infinity).

Orbits of Jupiter and Saturn:
(a) Suppose for every 1 orbit of Saturn around the sun, Jupiter completes 2.
(b) Suppose for sake of argument that they have always been orbiting from eternity past; yet oddly, in such a case, neither has completed the most orbits; they are the same (infinity).
(c) But this is absurd, because the longer they orbit, the further Saturn falls behind.

Reaching Today: If an infinite number of preceding events had to occur before today, then today could never be reached.  For example, we could never actually reach an event in the infinite future; only an event in the future by X years, where X is a finite number, however insanely large it may be.


Thus, infinity exists as an idea, but it cannot actually exist in the real world.  Thus, an infinity of past events could not have actually existed in the real world; and therefore, the universe had a beginning.

Can you give a single example of any reputable scientist or philosopher claiming that Jupiter & Saturn have been in existence an infinitely long time? I seriously doubt it!

@DHalsey--You're right, but it's simply meant as a thought experiment to demonstrate the impossibility of an infinite past.  I clarified the answer to indicate this, thanks.

There are actually ways to compare infinite quantities. For example, the numbers of natural numbers and odd natural numbers are both infinite, but there are twice as many of the former as the latter.

@DHalsey Unintuitive as it may seem, I believe mathematicians consider infinite sets to be exactly the same size when a one-to-one correspondence can be made between their members (i.e., the same order of infinity); which interestingly, is the case between positive odd numbers and positive integers; and stranger, even between all rational numbers and positive integers (e.g., here).  This is absurd in reality, but that's the point--that infinity exists nowhere in reality, but only as an idea.

The question of the beginning or no-beginning of the universe is not a “misunderstanding of applied language”.
The issue is more serious: Currently we lack the concepts to think about this question. It seems that our thoughts are trapped within traditional principles, which arise from thinking about every-day phenomena and events.
The endless discussion about beginning or no-beginning of the universe shows the limits of our current concepts and principles. One cannot tackle these questions using as tool our traditional concepts. At the moment, these questions have to be left open.
The question of the beginning of life on earth ("chicken or egg") seems to be an easier problem. It has been tackled by means of molecular chemistry and microbiology. The clue is the interdependent development of nucleid acids and aminoacids, the entangled development of information carriers and protein-synthesis on the basis of this information.

How an infinite causal chain can ever start is the problem laid out in Kant's 18th century 3rd Antinomy where he observes the contradiction in the two conjectures: [Thesis] that the causal chain must be initiated by a spontaneous event (freedom), and [Antithesis] that every event must be caused by another (i.e. determinism), c/o UC San Diego.
(The causality ideas go back to Aristotle e.g. Philip Klöcking's post)
The rational conclusion is that that ground is therefore indeterminate, and that the more determinate ground is the existing here & now, the beginning of which one might barely remember but have an intuition of.

The "exiting here & now" is therefore cast in a phenomenological sense: the 'here & now' of one's self.  This is the necessary ground for considering the question of existence.  Kant refers to the latter as "the ideal of pure reason":

from the totality of conditions for thinking objects in general
insofar as they can be given to me I infer the absolute synthetic
unity of all conditions for the possibility of things in general;
i.e., from things with which I am not acquainted as to their merely
transcendental concept, I infer a being of all beings, with which I am
even less acquainted through its transcendental concept, and of whose
unconditioned necessity I can make for myself no concept at all. This
dialectical syllogism I will call the ideal of pure reason.
A340/B398

Being/existence (of all beings) cannot be delineated but the next closest thing—that which experiences existence—can be.  And Dasein does have finitude: birth, life, death.  It began (relative to itself).
Wanting to know further from where or why the beginning began now reaches into Dasein's own products of scientific imagination, which are not up to the job since they consider chicken and egg objectively.  The world in which Dasein finds itself is not third-party objective; one is in the world, and one can intuit one's beginning of being in the world.
Thinking in terms of objective chicken and egg takes the familiar traditional view of dealing with things which we are inclined to fall back upon, but if we want to think about the beginning of everything we should be thinking of the 'everything' one is in, rather than the objective conjectures we have created.
This tendency of falling back on the objective is mentioned by Heidegger in Being & Time:

Our preparatory Interpretation of the fundamental structures of Dasein
with regard to the average kind of Being which is closest to it … will
make manifest, however, not only that Dasein is inclined to fall back
upon its world (the world in which it is) and to interpret itself in
terms of that world by its reflected light, but also that Dasein
simultaneously falls prey to the tradition of which it has more or
less explicitly taken hold. H.
21

i.e. infinite chains of mathematical conjecture.  An actual answer is found in the experiential.

If you want an Ancient Greek take that isn’t attached to a specific religion, and is very encompassing, you should research Eleatic Monism.
It’s a school Parmenides was a member of.
It says there is no change, only the appearance of change to mortals like us.
Here is an excellent intro to it
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DsPnFPKnInQ&pp=ygUORWxlYXJpYyBtb25pc20%3D

It took a Belgian Catholic priest, Georges Lemaitre, to propose an expanding universe in 1927. Einstein in 1915 had added a term to his General Relativity equations to produce the steady-state universe he assumed must be the case. It's pretty clear what Lemaitre's bias was, expansion implies a beginning, and a moment of Creation. It's interesting to me than in Buddhist thought they insist the cosmos is eternal, but has cycles, with the Creator deity simply the first into this realm after it's cycle of destruction, arriving from another realm, and when another later being arrived after the first wished company and it was simply mistaken in thinking it had created it.
As you say that moment of Creation leaves a puzzle. From what? How did the initial state of simplicity, of concentrated high energy and low entropy occur, given our experience says those are unlikely to occur by chance? We think time began with the Big Bang, so we may not be able to meaningfully talk about 'before' it. The idea there was also simply no space in the same way, is perhaps even more conceptually unsettling. Loop Quantum gravity and String Theory, propose our spacetime as emergent, as arising from a more fundamental and more complex domain. Another way to go is a new picture of an eternal cosmos, in the shape of Conformal Cyclic Cosmology (Wikipedia link). In short it could go either way, and in truth the real answer may well be beyond our comprehension, our cognitive biases about what we expect likely obscure our chance to see other options.
You seem to be after something more general. If you say why would the universe arise from nothing, you can equally say, why not? If the likelihood of something arising from nothing is low, it still happens, like very occassional spontaneous electron-positron pair production from vacuum fluctuations. The universe starting might have been incredibly unlikely, but in an infinite era of nothingness there could still be a finite chance of it. One idea goes that the energy of particles and the energy of their fields have opposite signs, implying if everything was together once again they would cancel out, and that the universe could literally be made from no energy (there are issues with this picture because energy is not conserved in an expanding universe, but every chance better theories that for instance account for dark-matter, could reconcile with this picture).
Causality as a notion is suspect in modern physics, which has replaced them with probabilities that conform to continuous symmetries, which is to say conservation laws. For discussion see here: Is the idea of a causal chain physical (or even scientific)? The TLDR is, we humans love narratives, to tell stories of things that happen to subjects, that's obe of our deepest cognitive biases. But it seems the cosmos is a pattern, not a story. What we really mean when we ask about a beginning is, how do we tell the story of how we got here, and most of all we want to find from that story, what 8s our place in it, how should we situate ourselves towards the world, the cosmos? Really it's a category error to go to physics for that, and it leads towards a kind of 'cargo cult' mentality towards whatever the new thing in physics is. They say the Greek medical model of balancing the humours was influenced by aquaducts and sewers needed for a healthy city. Newton's era saw a cosmos of clockwork. Victorians understood ourselves and the world as like engines. Now in the era of computing we coincidentally think the movements of quantum information and it's limitation to light speed (except in a sense for entanglement), are fundamental. We see what we are ready to see, and history teaches us it will probably be at best partial, and at worst dangerously wrong.
We should turn to different directions for meaning, for making sense of ourselves. And we should recognise the role of our choices, and of creativity in it, rather than thinking we can just find a sense of meaning and place by observing alone. The disentangling of meaning-cosmologies from physical cosmology discussed here: What are some philosophical works that explore constructing meaning in life from an agnostic or atheist view?

This seems like a purely scientific question.
Has our planet/universe always existed (in a more a less steady state, or perhaps more cyclical) or does it have a finite age? Aside from empirical evidence, I don't see any reason to exclude either possibility a priori.
Did anything precede the universe? According to General Relativity (the modern physics understanding of space and time), for some events there simply isn't a "before", in mathematically the same way as that on the surface of a sphere you cannot walk northward from the north pole (because it is one of the two points on a globe where "northward" has no valid meaning). The concept of time  itself (of events having something "before" them) only has a restricted domain of validity. This is counter-intuitive, but modern physics routinely rejects traditional intuitive axioms of logic. (For example, quantum mechanics suggests an object can have been in a particular location, and not been in that location, at the same time; Bell's theorem repudiated local realism. Also, conjectures that multiple temporal dimensions exist, and so the concept of a linear axis of time may be an approximation that isn't universally applicable, are being seriously investigated in particle physics. Obviously science has a propensity for enlarging the world, so it is also difficult to rule out the possibility of inferring knowledge of circumstances outside of what we currently call the universe.)
The whole issue usually arises in the context of apologetics, that make uncritical appeals for some things (the big bang) and not others (an animalistic anthropomorphic deity with particular human-centric agendas) to be explained by cause of something else pre-dating it. The apologetic has echoes of cognitive biases (attribution bias, narrative bias, etc) applicable for historiography; it seems to rely on audience's discomfort with unknowns.

You ask:


If you believe Kant's analysis of time, time is constructed by the mind, and therefore concepts of time, such as origins, are not muddled language, but conceptual tools for dealing with the physical world.
From Wikisource and Meiklejohn:

SS1 of the Transcendental Aesthetic: "From this investigation it will be found that there are two pure forms of sensuous intuition, as principles of knowledge a priori, namely, space and time."


SS7 B.:Time is nothing else than the form of the internal sense, that is, of the intuitions of self and of our internal state."


SS9: "...if we take away the subject, or even only the subjective constitution of our senses in general, then not only the nature and relations of objects in space and time, but even space and time themselves disappear; and that these, as phenomena, cannot exist in themselves, but only in us."

Thus, where we affix the origins of beginning, middle, and end, let's say on events is a judgement in accordance with the goals and values of the thinker. Consider when the last time you were in a rainstorm. How does one go about deciding when to assign the "beginning" to a rainstorm? Should it be when one becomes aware of it? When one is told by another when it started? Does the rainfall in one particular place count as the start, and if so, and one simply says, the first place, how many storms actually have known origins? Does the storm originate when the water hits the ground, or when it is falling? What if there's lightning before rain? Should the origin be given to the nearest hour? Nearest minute? Nearest second? Nearest fraction of a second? How often does anyone generally even have this data? Does that mean that rainstorms "approximately" begin?
Thus, when we say at the beginning of the rainstorm, we do so within the confines of the Wittgensteinian Sprachspiel. What is our purpose? For a meterologist, the storm begins probably when the first electronic sensor registers a particular type of precipitation. The meterologist is in the business of capturing scientifically real facts. In a court of law, the judge might only need to know the nearest hour and if the ground became wet to determine if a crime was committed because the trier of fact in that instance is interested in legal facts. Psychological facts are viewed through the lens of phenomenological discourse, and so a rainstorm begins as an experience when the first-person observer becomes aware of it in the same spirit of Berkeley's subjective idealism.
This is not a bug of language, but a feature. We use language as a tool to conceptualize and communicate, and by constructing in a particular way, we can reach particular ends. This is an acknowledged aspect of psychology observed by those who believe in the social construction of reality a view even proffered as relevant to scientific realism itself in the guise of scientific constructivism. Thus, it begs the question, what is an 'origin' anyway?
